# Ubuntu 20.04 - PC overheats and shuts down

Tags: lubuntu, shutdown, overheating, samsung

Laptop model: Samsung RC530

I am a Ubuntu user since few years, but basic user so kinda like at a newbie level.
I have this old Samsung RC530, and I wanted to bring some sparkle in it by installing the latest version of Ubuntu (20.04). Unfortunately after about 20 minutes of activity the computer reaches such a high temperature that decides to shut down automatically.
I tried with previous version of Ubuntu, different distributions, event with Lubuntu, same problem.
I got quite a decent result with Lubuntu 20.04 + TLP + thermald + CPUfreq, but still not satisfactory enough. The laptop does still heats up a lot and shuts down after a couple of hours.

Does anyone has any suggestion on how to resolve the issue?

Comment: Unless it was cleaned recently, would say dirt and dust built up inside.  Is good airflow from exhaust vent/s felt?  Is laptop on hard surface and/or raised up?  Canned air might help, but might also need to open up if dirt buildup on fan blades/hardware.

Comment: I did open it up and clean it as well. There was actually no dust at all inside, I was pretty amazed by it. I still gave it a round with canned air just in case.

Comment: Did a search on google ubuntu Samsung RC530 overheating.  Seems to be a few posts on issue.  Might be a bios fan issue, but you need to check posts to see if one helps.  If no dust and fan is working, laptop should not overheat unless bios and OS not communicating to fan or you are pushing laptop to work too hard.

Answer (score 0):

If you have tried different distros it’s probably not Ubuntu, it’s probably the hardware. Does it run like this on other OSs?

Comment: Right now the only real improved I noticed is by installing Pop!_OS, but still, after a few hours the pc shut down (I think when I opened up the 20th tab or something in Firefox and started a video). I was trying to push it a bit.
Doing a bit of research around I think the main issue here is the fact that this model comes with an Nvidia GeForce graphic card. I mean, I am not 100% sure this is the issue, but it seems quite likely. My main laptop runs Lubuntu, I guess I'll try to install Bumblebee on it and then switch harddisk to see if there is any improvement.

Comment: Would install sensors and maybe psensors.  Will allow you see what is heating and maybe check fan/s speed.  Having computer shut down because of heat does not do it any good.  Cooking the CPU often not good for long life

Answer (score 0):

Just to let you all know: seems like the issue was the graphic card.
I installed Ubuntu 20.04, added TLP + thermald + CPUfreq just in case and the I installed Bumblebee using the following command:

`sudo apt-get install bumblebee bumblebee-nvidia primus linux-headers-generic`

So far the temperature is been more than optimal. No overheating at all, not even after 3 hours of usage and a zoom session.
I would consider the issue solved. :)